# Jquery popup window including dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys what I want to do is when I click imagebutton a popup will appear with mask and a dynamic table will show the result (table) of the stored procedure.i use ajax method in order to call method from server side(creates dynamic table with checkboxes).at the end I just can see the mask but not the pop up .I checked everything but couldn't understand the why it is not shown.Can you please help.Here is the code.

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").click(function (event) {
            if (event.target.id == "Imagecig") {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#mask').fadeIn();
                $('#tabbed').fadeOut();
                cigarettepopup();
                $('#Literal1').fadeIn();
            }

            if (event.target.id == "btncancel") {
                $('#Literal1').fadeOut();
                $('#mask').fadeOut();
                $('#tabbed').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });

    function cigarettepopup() {
        $.ajax(
         {
             type: "POST",
             url: "Capacity_Templates_Maintenance_SKU.aspx/cigpopup",
             data: JSON.stringify({}),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function () {
                 $('#Literal1').show();
             }
         });
    }



</script>
```

and a literal to write dynamic table and the mask

```
<div id="mask"></div>
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

mask css:

```
  #mask
        {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 4;
        opacity: 0.4;
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)"; /* first!*/
        filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* second!*/
        background-color: gray;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        }
```

and server side

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    protected void cigpopup(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["JTI_Global_Capacity_TemplatesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        DataTable cigdatatable = new DataTable();           
        DataRow drcigdatatable = cigdatatable.NewRow();            

        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           {
                cnn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_CigaretteLength", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapt.Fill(cigdatatable);
                cnn.Close();
            }

        int numberofrowcigdatatable = cigdatatable.Rows.Count;

        StringBuilder dynamiccigpopup = new StringBuilder();

        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<asp:Panel id='cigarettepopup' runat='server' ScrollBars='Horizontal' BackColor='White' Height='400px' Width='300px' Style='z-index:111; background-color:White; position:absolute; left:35%; top:12%; border:outset 1px gray; padding:5px; display:none; overflow:scroll\'>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<table class='tablestyle'>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<thead>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<tr>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<th colspan='4'>Cigarette Length</th>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</tr>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</thead>");

        for( int i = 0 ; i < numberofrowcigdatatable/2 ; i ++)
        {

            dynamiccigpopup.Append("<tr>");                       
                dynamiccigpopup.Append("<th style ='text-align:left\'>");                   
                    dynamiccigpopup.Append(cigdatatable.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                dynamiccigpopup.Append("</th>");
                dynamiccigpopup.Append("<td>");
                    dynamiccigpopup.Append("<asp:CheckBox ID='CheckBox" + (i)+"'" + "runat='server' />");
                dynamiccigpopup.Append("</td>");            
            dynamiccigpopup.Append("</tr>");
        }


        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</table>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<table class='tablestyle'>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<tr>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<td>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<asp:Button ID='btnUpdate' CommandName='Update' runat='server' Text='Update' />");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</td>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<td>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("<input id='btncancel' type='button' class='btnClose' value='Cancel' />");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</td>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</tr>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</table>");
        dynamiccigpopup.Append("</asp:Panel>"); 

        Literal1.Text = dynamiccigpopup.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: I understood that code can not call serverside method but I don't know the reason